# Detect ExpandableListView group click

Tags: android, expandablelistview

I have a custom ExpandableListView elv and I am able to detect when a Child is clicked with the code below.

```
    elv.setOnChildClickListener(new OnChildClickListener() {
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                int childPosition, long id) {
```

However, when I change it to try to detect when a group item is clicked, this does not work. Does anyone know why?

Eclipse gives me the error:

> The method
>   setOnGroupClickListener(ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener)
>   in the type ExpandableListView is not
>   applicable for the arguments (new
>   OnGroupClickListener(){})

```
    elv.setOnGroupClickListener(new OnGroupClickListener() {
        public boolean onGroupClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition,
                long id) {
```

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Make sure you have imported `android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener` right or replace

> new OnGroupClickListener() {

with `new android.widget.ExpandableListView.OnGroupClickListener {`

Answer (score 0):

These methods can also be used inside `ExpandableListAdapter`
    public void onGroupExpanded(int groupPosition) {}
    public void onGroupCollapsed(int groupPosition) {}

Answer (score 0):

```
private ExpandableListView listView;


listView.setOnChildClickListener(new ExpandableListView.OnChildClickListener() {

        @Override
        public boolean onChildClick(ExpandableListView parent, View v, int groupPosition, int childPosition, long id) {

                      //get header
            TextView lbListenerHeader = parent.findViewById(R.id.lbListHeader);
            String data1= lbListenerHeader.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),data1 ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

                    //get list item
            TextView tv= (TextView) v.findViewById(R.id.lbListItem);
            ExpandableListView elv= (ExpandableListView) parent.findViewById(R.id.lvExp);
            String data= tv.getText().toString();
            Toast.makeText(getContext(),data ,Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();

            return true;
        }

    });
```